# Why does oh-my-zsh pick .zhistory instead of .zsh_history for the value of HISTFILE?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I tried googling about this but couldn't find any clue: Why does oh-my-zsh pick .zhistory instead of .zsh_history for the value of HISTFILE? Seems like .zsh_history is what more people would expect.

Comment: Why does OMZ do any of the things it does? Ask the dev...

Comment: ^this. [ask here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a question for the developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the ultimate decision comes from the software developer, this seems to be more in line with files `zsh` uses (from the man page):

```
   $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv
   $ZDOTDIR/.zprofile
   $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc
   $ZDOTDIR/.zlogin
   $ZDOTDIR/.zlogout
   ${TMPPREFIX}*   (default is /tmp/zsh*)
   /etc/zshenv
   /etc/zprofile
   /etc/zshrc
   /etc/zlogin
   /etc/zlogout
```

Ignoring a leading dot, **none of these use a `zsh_` prefix**, and only a few a full `zsh` prefix.  3 out of 4 of the dotfiles only have a `z` and so do 3 of 5 files in `/etc`.
The choice `.zhistory` seems to align with the majority here.